# Convert date and time input to sql datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am makeing a form where u can select a date and a time to make an apointment.
The fields are of the type date and time.

```
 <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="The date">
 <input type="time" name="time"  placeholder="The time">
```

I want to convert this input to a datetime format wich can be inserted with mysqli. what i tryd

```
  $datetime = $date . $time
```

but it isn't a valid datetime.
How can i convert it to a valid datetime so i can insert it in the database ?

edit

if i echo them after each other with a " " space between them i get 2018-05-05 03:05

the insert finishes but the data in the database is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 instead of the right date

Comment: What are the formats of $date and $time separately?

Comment: try something like a [date time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). Then you can format it as you like.

Comment: it is ment for mobile (made with bootstrap most datetime pickers dont work well on every platform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php the concate operator is `.` not `+`

so you need to do as

```
$datetime = $date.' '.$time;
```

If your date column in DB is Y-m-d H:i:s or in other words DATETIME then you can do as

```
$datetime = $date.' '.$time
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($datetime));
```

Now while inserting make sure you tread date as string.

In Direct insert you need to wrap the variable with quotes , in prepared statement you should bind param as `"s"`

Comment: sorry changed it still not a valid datetime.

Comment: what u get for $date and $time please echo them and see what data u see ?